# Redirect after an ajax request in a click event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm using JScript + ASP.NET. I got a form with 2 inputs (user and password) and a button. What I'm trying to do is to:

`1- Fire a click event` 
`2- Look inside a database if the user exist` 
`3- Give back the answer` 
`4- If the answer is true, POST some data to an other page AND redirect to it.`

I first tried to do this with ASP.NET. To POST data with ASP.NET I need to use PostBackUrl property, but the problem is that PostBackUrl ignore my click event.

I then tried to do this with jscript. On my click event (jquery), I use $.ajax to POST data to access my database, give the answer back in json...and I'm stuck there. In both method, I'm stuck at point 4.

ASP.NET

```
protected void SignIn_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clients client = (Clients)clientDAO.getUsername(text1.Text, password2.Text);
        if (client != null)
        {
            Session.Add("SessionNoClient", "1272");
            Session.Add("CurrentQuote", "-1");
            Session.Add("UnitSystem", "0");
            Session.Add("SessionAdministrator", "0");

            //How to redirect with POST here

        }
    }
```

JScript:

```
$("#m_bLogin").click(function () {
    var username = $("#text1").val();
    var password = $("#password2").val();
    var form = $("#formClient");
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../Class/LoginAjax.asmx/GetLoginInformation',
        data: "{ 'Name':'" + username + "','Password':'" + $("#password2").val() + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //My Json returns {"'Name':'Bob','Password':'1234'} and I'm not able to access Name or Password property. I tried data.d, data.d.Name, eval(data.d.Name) etc...
            form.submit();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../../Class/LoginAjax.asmx/GetLoginInformation',
    data: "{ 'Name':'" + username + "','Password':'" + $("#password2").val() + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        //My Json returns {"'Name':'Bob','Password':'1234'} and I'm not able to access Name or Password property. I tried data.d, data.d.Name, eval(data.d.Name) etc...
        form.submit();
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
        alert(error);
    }
}).done(function() { 
                      window.location.href = "YourNewPage.aspx";
                   });
```